# Add table cell using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sql, django

I have a HTML table with about four columns. I'm querying data using Ajax which is pulling information from a SQL table using Django. For the last column I need to have a dropdown menu.

An example of my JSON information I'm getting back from Ajax is:

```
[[1, "abc", 1,  ["[2013-09-30]", "[2013-12-02]"]]
[[2, "def", 1,  ["[2013-09-30]"]]
```

It basically shows ID, some string, frequency, and dates. I have rougly 25 different ID's. The first three data points in each ID all have the same information but the only thing thats different are my dates. Thats why I need a dropdown menu to select a date for each ID.

My problem is that my dropdown menu in my table doesn't work properly. It shows all the dates in the first row while all the other menus in the remaining rows are blank. I know theres a problem in my loop whereI append my dropdown menu to the table but I can't figure out whats happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
<table id = "templates" border = "1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th> Template ID </th>
        <th> Template Name </th>
        <th> Freq Multiplier </th>
        <th> As of Date </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

JQUERY

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function fill_table() {
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url: "/Tplots/ajax_temp/",
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(response) {
        for(var i = 0; i< response.length; i++) 
        {
            var item = response[i];
            for (var j = 0; j<10;j++) {
                var tempID = item[j];
                j = 1;
                var tempName = item[j];
                j =2;
                var freqM = item[j];
                j = 3;
                var as_of = item[j];
                j=4;
                $('#templates tbody').append("<tr id = i><td>" + tempID + "</td><td>" + tempName + "</td><td>" + freqM + "</td><td><select name='dropdown' id = 'dropdown'></select></td></tr>");               
                for (var k = 0; k<as_of.length; k++)
                {
                    var asofdate = as_of[k];
                    $('#dropdown').append($("<option>"+asofdate+"</option>"));
                }   
            }
        }
    }
})
    })
   </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not construct the table while processing the data?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function fill_table() {
$.ajax({
type:"GET",
url: "/Tplots/ajax_temp/",
dataType:'json',
success: function(response) {
    for(var i = 0; i< response.length; i++) 
    {
        $('#templates tbody').append("<tr>");            
        var item = response[i];
        for (var j = 0; j<4 ;j++) { 
            if (j <> 3) { // not the last column
                $('#templates tbody').append("<td>" + item[j] + "</td>");
            } else {
                $('#templates tbody').append("<td><select>");               
                for (var k = 0; k<as_of.length; k++) {
                    var asofdate = as_of[k];
                    $('#templates tbody').append("<option>"+asofdate+"</option>");
                } 
                $('#templates tbody').append("</td>"); 
            }
         }
         $('#templates tbody').append("</tr>");           
    }
})
})
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I thought of doing that earlier but was running into problems. For the example you wrote, I'm having another weird issue. In the else statement where your constructing the menu, there columns aren't correct. It shows me an empty dropdown menu under the Date Column and the column next to it then has the actual date information. It's treating the for statement as a separate cell and I don't know why.

Comment: Ah! I see what's wrong. Sorry that I didn't actually run the codes but just typed from the top of my head.   Try close the dropdown by adding </select> to the last </td>

Comment: No worries. Would you happen to know how to fix it?

Comment: Have you try to add </select> before the last </td>?  Right after the for loop:  } 
                $('#templates tbody').append("</select></td>");

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the HTML your script generated. Looks like you are assigning the same ID to all rows and drop downlist. Either assign a unique ID so the jQuery selector can select a correct row or save jQuery object you create as follows:

```
var $table = $("#templates tbody");
...

var $row = $("<tr>").appendTo($table);
...
var $td = $("<td>").appendTo($row);
var $select = $("<select>").appendTo($td);
for(var k=0,size=as_of.length; k<size; k++) 
  $("<option>").appendTo($select).text(as_off[k]);
...
```

Comment: Thanks! That definetly solved my dropdown menu problem. But the menu is no longer in line with the row. The menu isn't on the same row with the ID, name, and frequency cells.